# Edit form on JQGrid and ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I am having an issue on JQgrid when I select a row and press edit button. The problem is that I want a modal edit-form and it apears at the top of the page, but when I click on it, it close.
I review the JQgrid docs and search for examples but I can't make it work. I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 and JQgrid 1.4.1 and I attached the files JqDnr and Jqmodal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastsel;

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/DynamicGridData/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Nombre', 'Sponsor', 'Fecha de Evaluacion', 'Fecha Prevista de Fin', 'Planta', 'Sector', 'LOTO?', 'Trabajo en Altura?', 'Espacio Confinado?', 'Caliente?', 'Amianto?', 'Observaciones'],
            colModel: [
      { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left', editable: false },
      { name: 'Nombre', index: 'Nombre', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true },
      { name: 'Sponsor', index: 'Sponsor', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { size: 71} },
      { name: 'Fecha de Evaluacion', index: 'FechaEvaluacion', width: 90, align: 'left', editable: true },
      { name: 'Fecha Prevista de Fin', index: 'FechaPrevistaFin', width: 90, align: 'left', editable: true },
      { name: 'Planta', index: 'Planta', width: 70, align: 'left', editable: true },
      { name: 'Sector', index: 'Sector', width: 70, align: 'left', editable: true },
      { name: 'LOTO?', index: 'PermisoLOTO', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: true, formatter: "checkbox" },
      { name: 'Trabajo en Altura?', index: 'PermisoTrabajoAltura', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: true, formatter: "checkbox" },
      { name: 'Espacio Confinado?', index: 'PermisoEspacioConfinado', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: true, formatter: "checkbox" },
      { name: 'Caliente?', index: 'PermisoCaliente', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: true, formatter: "checkbox" },
      { name: 'Amianto?', index: 'PermisoAmianto', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: true, formatter: "checkbox" },
      { name: 'Observaciones', index: 'Observaciones', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '/scripts/themes/sand/images',
            caption: 'Tareas'
        }).navGrid("#pager", { edit: true });

    }); 
</script>
```

### Tareas

So, any help will be very helpfull. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce your probelm (see the test [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Hernan.htm)), but I can definitively say you that you have to change the values from the `name` property from the `colModel`. The `name` property will be used as the property name. It build additionally the ids of different elements in the Edit form. The id ementens like

```
id="Fecha Prevista de Fin"
id="tr_Fecha Prevista de Fin"
id="Amianto?"
id="tr_Amianto?"
```

and so on are bad. You can use Developer Tools of IE for example (press <kbd>F12</kbd> in IE) to examine the ids used in the Edit form of your current code. I strictly recommend you to use in the name property only characters from the set [a-zA-Z0-9] and start the name with a letter. No blanks inside of the name is permitted (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)).

By the way the parameter `imgpath` is [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5) since many jqGrid releases and you should remove it.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I am still having the issue, I added more information below.

Comment: @Hernan: Do you mean above and not below or one more your comment was not saved? Which problem you still have? The same problem, that the dialog is disappears after the first click on it? Where are the differences from my code and youth?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is this: "uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: restoreRow" when I select a row. It is what Firebug shows. I beleave that the problem is on Js files, I download everything and I get this error. Is there any specific order for <Scripts> includes?

Comment: @Hernan: of course it is very important. Look at my example and do the same or post your full HTML code with all JS included.